# How to add Azure User Assigned Managed Identity to Azure AD group in Terraform?

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I am trying to assign User Assigned Managed identity to AAD group. I have following Terraform code:

```
resource "azurerm_user_assigned_identity" "myid" {
  name                = "my_identity"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.somerg.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.somerg.location
}

data "azuread_group" "existinggroup" {
  display_name     = "existing_group"
  security_enabled = true
}

resource "azuread_group_member" "mygrpmember" {
  group_object_id  = data.azuread_group.existinggroup.id
  member_object_id = azurerm_user_assigned_identity.myid.id
}
```

During `plan` operation, I get following error:

```
Error: Value must be a valid UUID
```

When I change `myid.id` to `myid.principal_id` in last line of above code, I get an error during `apply` operation:

```
Error: Could not retrieve member principal object "4e83cd6b-d984-4484-8fb2-3ae6e1667ef9"
ODataId was nil
```

When I try with `myid.client_id` I get this during `apply`:

```
Error: Could not retrieve principal object "838c2662-5fe2-484c-bb52-f70994fa1d8b"
DirectoryObjects.BaseClient.Get(): Get "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/5989ece0-f90e-40bf-9c79-1a7beccdb861/directoryObjects/838c2662-5fe2-484c-bb52-f70994fa1d8b": GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/5989ece0-f90e-40bf-9c79-1a7beccdb861/directoryObjects/838c2662-5fe2-484c-bb52-f70994fa1d8b giving up after 9 attempt(s)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will work if you give `myid.principal_id` only . Please use the latest versions i.e. ***terraform Version `v1.1.0`*** , ***azuread version `v2.13.0`*** and ***azurerm version `v2.89.0`***   :

[image]

**I tested the same code in my environment like below :**

```
provider "azuread"{}

provider "azurerm"{
  features {}
}
data "azurerm_resource_group" "somerg"{
  name = "ansuman-resourcegroup"
}
resource "azurerm_user_assigned_identity" "myid" {
  name                = "ansuman-identity"
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.somerg.name
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.somerg.location
}

data "azuread_group" "existinggroup" {
  display_name     = "TestQA"
  security_enabled = true
}

resource "azuread_group_member" "mygrpmember" {
  group_object_id  = data.azuread_group.existinggroup.id
  member_object_id = azurerm_user_assigned_identity.myid.principal_id
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

[image]

Comment: I did not notice that I was using old version of `azuread` provider. Updating to version `2.13.0` fixed the problem. Thank you!

Comment: Glad to be of help @Krzysztof :)